# How to show value from ACF plugin field in e-mail?

Tags: php, wp-mail

The email is only show the Title of order. All values from the custom fields is empty.....

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

        if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) || get_post($post_id)->post_status != 'publish' )
            return;

        $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );

        $course_name = get_field('course_name',$post_id,false);

        $order_status =  get_field('order_status',$post_id,false);

        $order_price = get_field('order_cost',$post_id,false);

        $subject = 'New course have been created';

        $message = "New course have been created:\n\n";
        $message .= "Order number: " . $post_title . "\n" .  "Course name: " . $course_name . "\n" . "Course price: " .$order_price . "\n" . "Order status: " . $order_status ;

        wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), $subject, $message );
    }
```

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with your code. What’s the problem?

Comment: @JacobPeattie sorry, edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the thing in the order of functions, and the check :

```
 if(is_user_logged_in()){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    }
    else {
        $user_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
        $current_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    }
```